# EnvironmentError [Errno 39] "Directory not empty" while pip installing or updating a package in python3

Tags: python, pip

Posting both Q & A here as there wasn't a post on SO for this kind of error yet, and other links on web-search led to unresolved gihub issues. Here is me just updating a package in my virtual python environment:

```
(py36) $ pip install tornado -U
Collecting tornado
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/3f/5f89d99fca3c0100c8cede4f53f660b126d39e0d6a1e943e95cc3ed386fb/tornado-6.0.2.tar.gz (481kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 476kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: tornado
  Building wheel for tornado (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/nikhil/.cache/pip/wheels/61/7e/7a/5e02e60dc329aef32ecf70e0425319ee7e2198c3a7cf98b4a2
Successfully built tornado
Installing collected packages: tornado
  Found existing installation: tornado 5.1.1
    Uninstalling tornado-5.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tornado-5.1.1
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/mnt/STUFF/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/~ornado'
```

So how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the actual folder highlighted in the error message:

```
/mnt/STUFF/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/~ornado
```

I found that there was another one of those `.fuse-hidden...` files sitting there which is typically while I'm using Geany (text editor) in my folders during its runtime, which then disappear after I've saved by files and I refresh my folder. Somehow such a file got created here as well and never got removed. Note that this might be my OS's fault and not Geany's - IDK. Anyways I removed the file myself and ran the upgrade command and no errors this time.

Answer (score 1):

For me the log says:

```
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
```

After adding `--use-pep517` to my pip install command, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem where creating a built distribution archive of my own python package using wheel (`python setup.py bdist_wheel`) resulted in the same error message. Problem was resolved once I closed all open files of the package I wanted to generate a built distribution from (i.e. I closed my text-editor).

As it is the same error and similar solution but occurring at a very different situation, I created its own stack-overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204162/environmenterror-errno-39-directory-not-empty-while-generating-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue installing a specific pandas version in a virtual environment, with the following error:

```
$ pip install pandas==1.3.0
...
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/usr/home/user_k/codes/python/venv_3-77/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~andas/_libs/tslibs'
```

Checking the permissions of this directory, it had no read or execute permission for user_k. Made the change to match other sub-directories in this directory:

```
(venv_3-77) user_k@hostname:~/codes/python/venv_3-77/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~andas/_libs$ ll
total 12
...
d-w------- 2 user_k users 4096 Nov 10 17:45 tslibs
...
venv_3-77) user_k@hostname:~/codes/python/venv_3-77/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~andas/_libs$ chmod 755 tslibs
```

Post this directory permission correction, package install worked.