# EnvironmentError [Errno 39] “Directory not empty” while generating distribution archives in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When generating a built distribution archive for my own python package using

```py
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

(following the [Packaging Python Projects Tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives)) - the following error occured:

```
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
running install
running install_lib
copying build/lib/deepnog/models/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/deepnog/models
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing DeepNOG.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to DeepNOG.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to DeepNOG.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'DeepNOG.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'DeepNOG.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/DeepNOG-0.1.0-py3.7.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying DeepNOG.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/DeepNOG-0.1.0-py3.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
adding license file "LICENSE" (matched pattern "LICEN[CS]E*")
error: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/DeepNOG-0.1.0-py3.7.egg-info'
```

I could not find the exact problem described on stack-overflow (as well as only unresolved github issues elsewhere). Therefore I am posting here both the question and answer. A very similar problem occuring in a different context is described and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789261/environmenterror-errno-39-directory-not-empty-while-pip-installing-or-updati) which led me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was resolved once I closed all open files of the package I wanted to generate a built distribution from (i.e. I closed my text-editor).

Answer (score 0):

Change the Python interpreter you're using to the default. I solved mine by using the default python interpreter rather than the project's interpreter.

You can do this in VS Code by navigating to the **view>>command palette>>Python: Select Interpreter** and choose the default environment or the created virtual environment you are using.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.